# Cannot take ownership of file so I can delete it

Tags: windows, bittorrent

```
takeown.exe /F btweb_installer.exe
ERROR: Access is denied.
```

I installed btweb_installer.exe, but my Avira antivirus quanrantined the file, because it contained a virus and now I have an exe file with file size 0 byte.

Comment: Try unlocker 1.92 (Major Geeks)

Comment: The object could not be deleted.

Comment: Make a new Windows User, make the user a member of Administrators, log into the new user and see if you can delete it that way.